# Google Map on JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to run this JavaScript function on asp.net button click event.But map didn't get loaded when i click the button.Here is my code.Please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
```

//This is my JavaScript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layerl0;
    function initializes() 
    {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.003575733881323, 81.298828125),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      });
      layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "'geometry'",
          from: '4757916',
          where: "Address='kerala'"
        },
        map: map
      });
    }
  </script>
```

// This is asp.net code

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 421px"></div>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="initializes()" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm assuming the button is causing a postback to occur, thus stopping the JS from running in the client's browser. Use a standard html `button` or `input type=button` element instead of an `asp:Button`. That will just cause headaches if all you're using it for is client-side interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from my comment above:

> I'm assuming the button is causing a postback to occur, thus stopping the JS from running in the client's browser. Use a standard html button or input type=button element instead of an asp:Button. That will just cause headaches if all you're using it for is client-side interaction

And a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbjAD/